# Applying certain CSS to images over specified size

Tags: javascript, iphone, css

Here's my predicament; I'm working on a simple iPhone site (it's a port for my blog). I have this issue; In order for my blog to at least look somewhat nice, I need to put a boarder around every image over a certain size, and then center said images.

The site's content is literally an RSS feed displayed with some simple javascript and fancied up with some CSS. The CSS bit is what I'm trying to work on right now. Any help would be hugely appreciated (I'm rather new to javascript, so I realllly won't feel condescended if you elaborate slightly).

Comment: JavaScript lesson 1: It's **not** the same as Java. I've updated the tag :)

Comment: Shit, did I actually say "Java" in the tag? -_- I ACTUALLY know java. That's embarrassing. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I'll break it down. The Javascript(done with jQuery) will iterate through every image on the page once it's loaded. If the height or width of the image is over 300, it appends the class 'oversized' to the parent. Change each instance of 300 in the script to what you consider oversized.

The CSS basically just consists of the `text-align:center;` to center the image in the `<div>` and then the border for the image.

[Try the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YynnY/)

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').each(function(e) {
        if (($(this).height() > 300) || ($(this).width() > 300)) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('oversized');
        }
    });
});​
```

### CSS

```
.oversized { /* make the image align to center */
    text-align: center;
}
.oversized * { /* Anything in the oversized div will have a border (the image) */
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

​

Comment: To implement jquery, i simply have to download it and then call it from within my index.html file, correct? 


<script type="text/javascript" src="orientation.js"></script>

Comment: Yeah to implement jQuery you need to link to it in that way, with orientation.js being the path to the jquery.js